How to get element that has exact text instead of contains text in puppetteer?
Consider this:
<select>
  <option value="1">ba</option>
  <option value="2">ab</option>
  <option value="3">a</option>
  <option value="4">b</option>
</select>

When I use this:
await page.locator('option ::-p-text(a)')
await page.locator('option ::-p-text(b)')

I got the option with ba instead of a or b. This is the intended behaviour according to the docs:

Text selectors will select "minimal" elements containing the given text,
even within (open) shadow roots. Here, "minimum" means the deepest elements
that contain a given text, but not their parents (which technically will also
contain the given text).

How to get element that has exact text instead of contains text in puppetteer?

This question is similar to: How do you click on an element with text in Puppeteer?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See this answer which shows multiple ways to match exact text in Puppeteer.

@ggorlen my question is about exact not contains. the linked question/answer is not similar. the title of my question clearly explain that I need "exact" not just "contains". the linked question/answer is exactly what I mean by "instead of".

Did you read the answer I linked? It's the most thorough treatment of the question, both contains and exact (the question doesn't specify which, so both are relevant to it), and it doesn't make sense to regurgitate that here. Your answer is just a repost of a small subset of that answer, without broader context, and is not the typical function you'd want to use for this. So this thread really should link to the canonical, it's basically a duplicate.

I see. I agree with you that your answer there clearly answer my question. But, the intent of my question and that question is different. That's why I can't find your answer before and instead I got the answer from here while I'm looking something about XPath.
Feel free to link your answer here, I'll gladly accept your answer.
In any case, I still don't agree that my question is a duplicate of that question.

I have linked my answer here in the comments, but I'm not going to repost that as an answer. Just because the question is slightly different doesn't mean we need to repeat all of the information in the canonical here.

I got it. The answer is
await page
  .locator(
    `::-p-xpath(//option[text()='a'])`,
  )
  .wait()

See this for more thorough explanation.

text() doesn't normalize whitespace, so it won't match <option> a</option>. See this answer and consider using normalize-space() instead.
